# swift 3 tableView with 2 tableCellsViews acting weird

Tags: swift3, xcode8

I have a viewController that has has a tableView and the tableView has 2 tableViewCells. cell1 and cell2.

This is my IB view

[image: builder view]

this is my code

```
import UIKit

class userMenuViewController: BaseViewController,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var myArr = ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    return (myArr.count)
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 100.0;
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{

    let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell1TableViewCell
    let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell2TableViewCell

    switch (indexPath.row) {
    case 0:
        return (cell1)
    case 1:
        return (cell2)
    case 2:
        return (cell1)
    default:
        return (cell1)
    }
}


public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
    print(indexPath.row)
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    addSlideMenuButton()

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



}
```

When I run simulator, i get the exact opposite of what i asked for as you can see from screenshot bellow

[image: screenshot of view]

Weirder still, before i added to viewDidLoad the following code:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

when simulator was run the cell orders were correct but they changed from one to the other when clicked and the first cell [0] could not be clicked

any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: check the value of your cells' `Identifier` in attributes inspector to make sure you didn't mix up the identifiers

Comment: Are you sure the custom classes and the identifiers are properly assigned to the cells in Interface Builder? Consider to use a more distinguishable naming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing

```
let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell1TableViewCell
let cell2 = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell2TableViewCell

switch (indexPath.row) {
case 0:
    return (cell1)
case 1:
    return (cell2)
case 2:
    return (cell1)
default:
    return (cell1)
}
```

to

```
switch (indexPath.row) {
case 0:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell1TableViewCell
    return cell
case 1:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell1TableViewCell
    return cell
case 2:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell1TableViewCell
    return cell
default:
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! PrefCell1TableViewCell
    return cell
}
```